# How to prevent history.push if location didn't change in react-router4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

If current page is `site.com/one` and I'm clicking on `<Link to='/one'>One</Link>`, it pushing new item to history on every click (but location don't changing). How to prevent that? It's really stupid behaivor.

Comment: I can't confirm that. What makes you think that a new item is added to the history?

Comment: It's how <Link> works

Comment: But did you confirm that? And how did you confirm that? I created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y38j6637k1) example and it doesn't behave like you described it. No matter how often I click a Link to the same target it doesn't add an entry to the history. Please share a minimal example that reproduces the behavior you described.

Comment: Hm, really. But in my case it works by another way. I'll try to figure out.

Comment: Well, your code doesn't work correctly, as I expected. Try to download files (from https://codesandbox.io/s/pmny46nky0) and launch the project. Then try to click to One link multiple times. Every time you'll get a new item in browser history.

Comment: trixn, did you get my message? Try to download and launch your project. I don't know why people disliked this post. It's a real problem. Stupid people.

Comment: +1 You are correct. The sandbox did not behave the same as normal browser does. I created a custom `Link` component that fixes that issue. Please see my answer. There is also an open issue for that problem in the `history` library that `react-router` internally uses. This may be fixed in future versions of it. In the mean time you can use the solution I provided in my answer.

Comment: Disable that link using history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is also described in [issue #470](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/470). It may be fixed in the future. In the meanwhile you could use your own link component that does a `replaceState` when the location matches with the current one:

**link.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Link as ReactRouterLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import {createPath} from 'history';

const Link = ({to, replace, ...props}) => (
    <Route path={typeof to === 'string' ? to : createPath(to)} exact>
        {({match}) => (
            <ReactRouterLink {...props} to={to} replace={replace || !!match} />
        )}
    </Route>
);

Link.propTypes = ReactRouterLink.propTypes;
Link.defaultProps = ReactRouterLink.defaultProps;

export default Link;
```

**app.js**

```
import Link from './link'; // use the custom Link component instead of the react-router Link

const App = () => {
    <ul>
        <li><Link to={{ pathname: '/one', search: 'foo=bar' }}>one</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/two">two</Link></li>
    </ul>
}
```

The component uses the `Route` component to check if the current location matches the location that was defined by the `to` prop of the link. If it matches the link will be rendered with the `replace` prop set to `true`. This makes sure the history item will be replaced instead of added.

Everything else will work the same as the normal `Link` component. Just use this component instead of the original `Link` and it will work the way you want it.

**Working example:**

[image: Edit y38j6637k1]

Comment: Heh, passing props to each <Link> is not good idea. What if they are in another file and components?

Comment: @DarynK. I don't get your point. You can use that Component as a replacement for the normal Link.

Comment: @DarynK. I updated my example and the sandbox to better make clear how the component is intended to be used. This solution is based on how `react-router` internally uses the `Route` component to style links using the `NavLink` component. It is a short, robust and clean solution that fixes the issue while there is no patch for it in the `history` module.

Comment: How to pass props to each <CustomLink>? It's impossible!

Comment: @DarynK. You use `CustomLink` the same as you would use `Link`. It is just a wrapper around the original `Link` component. Put it in its own file -> import it from there where you want to use it -> use it **instead of** the original `Link`. See the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y38j6637k1) for an example.

Comment: I've got this error: Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: @DarynK. Did you export the component correctly and import it like: `import Link from './link'` ? Just look at the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/y38j6637k1). Copy the contents of `link.js` into a file in your project and import the component from there when you want to use it.